# My background music gets played twice (at the same time)

Tags: ios, swift, viewdidload

When i launch my app, a background music starts to play. But when i press start and play the game (in another viewcontroller) and then go back to menu (the first view controller) the song starts again but while the same song is still playing (result = hearing it twice at the same time).Very annoying. This is my viewDidLoad function (probably where my problem is). Can someone help me (by explaining or giving code) playing the music only the first time that the view loads ?

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // get path of audio file
    let myFilePathString = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Background Music Loop (Free to Use)", ofType: "mp3")
    if let myFilePathString = myFilePathString {

        let myFilePathURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: myFilePathString)
        do { try myAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: myFilePathURL)
            myAudioPlayer.play()
            myAudioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1
        }catch{
            print("error")
        }
  }
}
```

Comment: When you say you "go back to menu" are you actually going back to the original menu or are you creating a new menu and going to that one?

Comment: I'm going back to the original menu (the view controller that starts the music when loaded)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`myAudioPlayer.play` will simply be called again, since the VC runs the `viewDidLoad()` method again.

**My idea:**

declare a variable

```
var x = false
```

next step - make a condition on your audio player to play.

```
if x == false { // your code here }
```

when triggering the Segue from the other VC try to use the `prepareForSegue` method.

So on **2nd ViewController**

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
{
    if segue.identifier == "yourIdentifier" {
        let destinationController = segue.destinationViewController as! // Controller Name here
        destinationController.x = true
    }
}
```

This will set the x to true and the music doesn't run again.

Comment: thanks !! but just  a little question cause I'm still noob (just began with programming) your last comment is // controller name . The name of which controller the first or the second one ? And for the segue identifier is it possible that i have to give it a name or should there be a name already

Comment: OOH IT WORKED THANK YOU SO MUCH !! Will you answer my future questions as well ?

Comment: glad to hear :) if you still need help with the view controller name: you are doing a segue from the 2nd to the first. so the destination is the first VC. by clicking on the segue in main.Storyboard you can edit the segue identifier in the right column. add the name of it there and put the same name into "yourIdentifier". hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the functionality you want.

If you only want the background music to play when the menu view controller is on screen you could make the file name and player variables properties on the view controller and then in viewWillAppear do

```
Player.play
```

And then when a user navigates away from the page stop it playing in the viewDidDissappear function.

If you want the music to always play in the background then it might be worth creating your own class for it and providing a sharedInstance on the app delegate so that you can manage a single instance of the player throughout the application.